# Get string value out of a KeySym value

Tags: rascal

Is there a way to get the string value out of a KeySym value?
For example, out of `keyPrintable("a")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the `KeySym` value is a `keyPrintable`, you can just get it using the `key` property. For instance

```
KeySym kv = ... // something that yields a KeySym
str s = kv.key;
```

If you don't know it's a `keyPrintable` you can either check to see if it was built using that constructor, or use pattern matching. So, either

```
if (kv is keyPrintable) {
  // code that uses kv.key to get back the value
}
```

or

```
if (keyPrintable(str s) := kv) {
  // code that can now use s, which is the key
}
```

You can also ask if kv has that field, and then use it:

```
if (kv has key) {
  // code that uses kv.key
}
```

Once you introduce a field name in a constructor, and it has a specific type, you know that same field name has that same type in any additional constructors for the same datatype. So, once we know field `key` is type `str`, field `key` has to be `str` in any value of type `KeySym`. That is why it's fine to see if `kv` has field `key` and then treat it as a `str`, nobody could come along later and add a new constructor for `KeySym` where `key` has a different type.